# Opengles 1.1 render complete image to array

Tags: android, opengl-es

Is there any way to render image to array without using glreadpixel since i'm going to use it for color picking object and reading pixel from framebuffer seem to have a problem with different hardware.

for example
    there is image which came from render pipeline and normally render to screen but i want opengles to render it to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be the only way... in GL ES 2.0 you may use framebuffer object, that are a bit more flexible than the glReadPixel but still you have to render pixels to the texture.

what is this array? array of GLubytes? texture is also an array in some way... a block of memory inside the OpenGL.